# Selenium in Docker "element not interactable" but works locally

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So i wrote python script to scrap some data from real estate market page. And it works very well locally.
I want to dockerize the app now and suddenly selenium is facing issue with interactable element (here's html of it)

```
<input autocomplete="off" inputmode="decimal" name="areaMin" type="text" id="areaMin" placeholder="Powierzchnia od" aria-label="Powierzchnia od" data-cy="search-form--field--areaMin">
```

The exact error message from container looks like this:

```
File "/app/./scrapping_nieruchomosci.py", line 38, in <module>
2024-01-15 13:48:02     initialize_search(driver=driver, min=MIN, max=MAX, city=CITY_PHRASE)
2024-01-15 13:48:02   File "/app/utils/helper_functions.py", line 30, in initialize_search
2024-01-15 13:48:02     min_pow.send_keys(min)
2024-01-15 13:48:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 231, in send_keys
2024-01-15 13:48:02     self._execute(
2024-01-15 13:48:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 403, in _execute
2024-01-15 13:48:02     return self._parent.execute(command, params)
2024-01-15 13:48:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
2024-01-15 13:48:02     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
2024-01-15 13:48:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
2024-01-15 13:48:02     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
2024-01-15 13:48:02 selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
2024-01-15 13:48:02   (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=120.0.6099.216)
```

Heres my dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get clean

# Set display port as an environment variable
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "./scrapping_nieruchomosci.py"]
```

and here's my code:

```
def initialize_search(driver, min, max, city):
    driver.get("https://www.otodom.pl/")

    time.sleep(5)
    print("Checking the cookies!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    try:
        cookies_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
        cookies_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')))
        cookies_button.click()
        print("Clicked on cookies")
    except:
        print("No cookies")
        print(driver.current_url)
    print(driver.current_url)
    #print(driver.page_source)

    time.sleep(10)
    min_pow = driver.find_element(By.ID, value="areaMin")
    #this prints the input element of html from above (the same  prints when run locally)
    print(min_pow.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
    min_pow.send_keys(min)
```

```
import time
import json
from datetime import datetime

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from utils.dicts import css_selectors_dict
from utils.helper_functions import get_links_list, get_row_dict, initialize_search

CITY_PHRASE = "Plock"
MIN = 50
MAX = 55
# Get current time and format it as a string in "year-month-day-hour-minute" format
current_time = datetime.now()
time_string = current_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")

# Chrome options to run with selenium
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') # /uses tmp instead of shared memory
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

initialize_search(driver=driver, min=MIN, max=MAX, city=CITY_PHRASE)
```

Interesting is that the cookies request is interactable and i got print confiramtion that cookies button was clicked the issue is only later.
I rulled out timing issues and used for example
min_pow = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "areaMin")))

and instead of element not interactable i just got Timeout

Thanks for help everyone

Answer (score 0):

I recommend filling this value using JS instead of selenium code. Sometimes some elements/buttons can't be interacted with using Selenium. To use JS, add the following line:

```py
driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementById('areaMin').value='{MIN}';")
```

Doing stuff using JS sometimes saves you time and is much more consistent than using normal Selenium.

Now for the reason why this element isn't intractable, I honestly don't know, but most cases would be that there's another element kinda floating above the element you're trying to interact with or the element can't be pressed by a real mouse (since selenium is like a testing tool, it deploys an actual browser and simulates clicks).